# How to calculate network system downtime

Tags: networking, system, downtime

Here are two systems, A and B. How to calculate the downtime of each.

For A, should it be: 0.01 * 10 * 6 * 12 = 7.2 hours/year?

A system has 10 physical nodes, if any of those nodes failed, the whole system go down. The probability of failure for a individual node is 1% per month, and the downtime is 6h for fixing. Then what is the downtime for the whole system per year.

B system has 10 physical nodes, if 9 out of 10 nodes is running the whole system can function as normal. The probability of failure for a individual node is 1% per month, and the downtime is 6h for fixing. Then what is the downtime for the whole system per year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are talking about expected downtimes here, so we'll have to take a probabalistic approach.

We can take a Poisson approach to this problem.  The expected failure rate is 1% per month for a single node, or 120% (1.2) for 10 nodes in 12 months.  So you are correct that 1.2 failures/year * 6 hours/failure = 7.2 hours/year for the expected value of A.

You can figure out how likely a given amount of downtime is by using 7.2 as the lambda value for the poisson distribution.

Using R: ppois(6, lambda=7.2) = 0.42, meaning there is a 42% chance that you will have less than 6 hours of downtime in a year.

For B, it's also a Poisson, but what's important is the probability that a second node will fail in the six hours after the first failure.

The failure rate (assuming a 30 day month, with 120 6 hour periods) is 0.0083% per 6 hour period per node.

So we look at the chances of two failures within six hours, times the number of six hour periods in a year.

Using R: dpois(2.0, lambda=(0.01/120)) * 365 * 4 = 0.000005069

0.000005069 * 3 expected hours/failure = 54.75 milliseconds expected downtime per year.  (3 expected hours per failure because the second failure should occur on average half way through the first failure.)

Comment: I generally agree with your solution but want to say some words.
We don't consider cases with linked failures when third failure appears during downtime caused by previous failures.
And fourth etc.
The probability of these cases is so small and can be neglected.
But can't be neglected if the probability of failure will be big enough.
It seems to me that this problem can be solved by approaches in the theory of waiting lines.

Comment: The estimate of 54.75 milliseconds is vastly different from mine: 9.84 seconds. At first I was going to solve this by basic simulation but probabilities are so small that it turned out to be tricky. I would like to know if I made a basic mistake in my reasoning or didn't take some effect into account, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1% failure rate / month / node has a probability of 0,00138889% to fail at any given hour. I used binomial distribution in Excel to model the probability of N node failures when there are 8760 h/y * 10 nodes = 87600 "trials". I got these results:

```
0 failure:   29.62134067 %
1 failure:   36.03979837 %
2 failure:   21.92426490 %
3 failure:    8.89142792 %
4 failure:    2.70442094 %
5 failure:    0.65805485 %
6 failure:    0.13343314 %
...and so forth
```

N failures would cause 6N hours of downtime (asusming they are independent). Then for each 6N hours of single-node downtime the probability of having **none** of other 9 nodes to fail is `(100% - 0,00138889%) ^ (9 * 6N)`.

Thus expected two-node downtime is `P(1 node down) * (1 - P(no other node down)) * 6 hours / 2` (divided by two because on average 2nd failure occurs in mid-point of other node being repaired). When summed over all `N` numbers of failures I got expected two-node downtime of 9.8 seconds / year, now idea how correct estimate this is but should give a rough idea. Quite brute-force solution :/

[image: Excel calculations]